# Why do I get TextView.append runtime exception?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, textview

I have an inner private AsyncTask which will access the outer, global TextView and uses that to append a String line read in in that AsyncTask class.  I can read in fine, but when I try to append the line to the TextView, I get fatal runtime exception.

Here is the AsyncTask code:

```
private class StreamTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
    private static final int BUFFER_LENGTH = 1024 * 8; // Adjust to taste
    String TAG2 = "StreamTask";
    // Param #0 = file name
    // Param #1 = charset name
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.d(TAG2, "in doInBackground");

        if (params.length != 2) {
            Log.d(TAG2, "AsyncTask has 2 params");
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        int chars = 0;
        CharsetDecoder cd = Charset.forName(params[1]).newDecoder();
        try{
            Log.d(TAG2, "in first try block");
            FileInputStream inputStream = null;
            Scanner sc = null;
            try {
                Log.d(TAG2, "in second try block");
                inputStream = new FileInputStream(params[0]);
                Log.d(TAG2, "inputstream set "+params[0]);
                sc = new Scanner(inputStream, params[1]);
                Log.d(TAG2, "scanner set: "+params[1]);
                while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                    Log.d(TAG2, "in while block");
                    String line = sc.nextLine();
                    Log.d(TAG2, "this line is: "+line);
                    // System.out.println(line);
                    textView.append(line);//This is where the problem is~~~
                }
                // note that Scanner suppresses exceptions
                if (sc.ioException() != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG2, "throws ioException");
                    throw sc.ioException();
                }
            } 
            catch(FileNotFoundException e){}

            finally {
                Log.d(TAG2, "in finally...");
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                if (sc != null) {
                    sc.close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){}  
        return chars;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Jason

Answer (score 3):

You can not update UI from `doInBackground()` of AsynTask. Because it runs on other thread (which can not update UI directly).

You can update UI fom `onPostExecute()` which runs on UI thread. Like

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String b){
    textView.append(b);
}
```

Read about [AsynTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

---

If your need is to update UI from doInBackground only, you can use `runOnUiThread` like below

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
            textView.append(line);
     }
});
```

---

[***Communicating with the UI Thread***](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html) is a good article.